# Getting raster values on grid nodes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, r, vector-grid

I have my raster layers of Digital Elevation Model, aspect, slope and curvature for a certain region. In this region I want to apply a grid with a certain spacing in its nodes, and then get the corresponding values of DEM, aspect, slope, curvature for the grid nodes sites. I have tried in ArcMap 10.2 to apply the fishnet, but it doesn't seem to give me this option (get raster values exactly on grid nodes).

Any idea on how can I perform this in ArcMap or R?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be possible to do using ArcGIS for Desktop by:

1. Using [Create Fishnet (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000) to make label points that are located where you want them i.e. perhaps offsetting their origin coordinate by half a fishnet cell height and width.
2. Using [Extract Values to Points (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002t000000) which:

> Extracts the cell values of a raster based on a set of point features
>   and records the values in the attribute table of an output feature
>   class.

If you do not have a Spatial Analyst license then it should be possible to emulate the functionality needed for step 2 by using ArcPy cursors and [GetCellValue_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m8000000).

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with `raster::extract` in R:

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(setNames(replicate(4, raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))),
                    c('elev', 'aspect', 'slope', 'curv')))
```

Create a matrix of x,y coordinates:

```
xy <- expand.grid(x=seq(0, 1, 0.15), y=seq(0, 1, 0.15))
```

Sample the layers of `s` at each of the points in `xy`:

```
z <- cbind(xy, extract(s, xy))

head(z)

#      x y       elev    aspect     slope      curv
# 1 0.00 0 0.58459710 0.5485367 0.7734856 0.1174515
# 2 0.15 0 0.76056989 0.2542434 0.9856833 0.1138580
# 3 0.30 0 0.02464270 0.7523499 0.5728196 0.7115031
# 4 0.45 0 0.71639151 0.8863490 0.9395645 0.8747950
# 5 0.60 0 0.01663264 0.9300632 0.1605902 0.4179168
# 6 0.75 0 0.75622080 0.8461625 0.7695283 0.3135819
```